# sys.dm_exec_query_stats returns only a few rows

Tags: sql-server

What is the reason, that select * from sys.dm_exec_query_stats returns only a few rows? The record count differs from 3 to 30.

On different server/machine I get more than 8.5k rows.
Is this an indicator for memory pressure?

Comment: isn't it like the number of operations is larger on other server?

Answer (score 1):

It returns the performance statistics for cached query plans, look at this link for more details : [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-query-stats-transact-sql)

Its going to show a different number on any given machine depending on how many query plans have been cached

Comment: Thanks. On both server there is almost the same workload (same application). But on one machine there 50 instances installed and on the other only 5.

Comment: One row shows each separate query for a plan so if a plan has 10 query's then there will be 10 rows, if it has 1 then only one row. count the distinct plan_handle to see how many plans are in each one

Comment: I execute a select "A".
Then I query sys.dm_exec_query_stats and see two execution plans. 
One is the execution plan for select "A" and the other execution plan is for select sys.dm_exec_query_stats itself.
After a while (two or three seconds later) I query sys.dm_exec_query_stats again and I get only one plan for select sys.dm_exec_query_stats.
How long will this information be saved by SQL Server? On the other machine I have execution plans which are much older (3 or 4 days).

Comment: How the plan cache works cant really be explained in the 600 characters you get. There a points based system which uses complexity and frequency to determine how long something should stay there for. Watch a couple or YouTube videos on SQL Server Internals or the plan cache and it will make more sense. This is really good : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=34VqSliEfsc